# Dynamic routes in Phoenix Framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The user accesses the following route: `www.example.com/api/users/x`, where x is variable.

How to get x and create routes with dynamic responses?

*Automatically translated.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your router.ex you need to write something like following -

```
get "/api/users/:x", SomeController, :actionName
```

Now in your controller, you need to use patten matching to get the value of x from _params, ie:

```
def actionName(conn,  %{"x" => x}) do
    # now x is available here
end
```

For more details, http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/controllers

Comment: This topic is nicely presented in official Phoenix Framework documentation guide. Please take a look here: 
  http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/adding-pages#section-another-new-page

Comment: The link above is dead; see https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/request_lifecycle.html#another-new-page instead.